# Scrollbar not responding to maximum value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to add a custom scroll bar to panel control on windows form. Every thing is working fine except Maximum value.

The panel contain file names from provided path. In order to visible the scroll bar I used  variable. The variable is incremented when a new file is added to the panel. Label control is used to display file name. After all files added to panel. I make a check to see if there are any file outside the panel view. If there are then the scroll bar is made visible and the maximum value is set to required height variable. Required height variable is total height of controls. All components are added though tools.

Here is the code for MainForm class.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        file obj=new file();
        Label[] file_names;

        public MainForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
// viewpanel is the name of panel to display the file name
            viewpanel.AutoScroll=false;
// viewscrollbar is the name of scroll bar associated with viewpanel
            viewscrollbar.ValueChanged+= new EventHandler(viewscroll);
            viewscrollbar.Enabled=true;
            viewscrollbar.Visible=false;
        }
```

The code for view update panel. This function goes through label array and add each label to viewpanel.

```
void updateviewpanel()
        {
         //reheight is a variavle used to calculate total height     //required.
            int reheight=0;
            int yaixs=0;
            for(int i=0;i<file_names.Length;i++)
            {

                file_names[i].Location=new Point(0,yaixs);
                file_names[i].Height=20;
                file_names[i].Width=viewpanel.Width-5;
                file_names[i].BorderStyle=BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

                yaixs=yaixs+20;
                //the reheight variable is increment each time a label is added to panel.
                reheight=reheight+20;
                viewpanel.Controls.Add(file_names[i]);

            }// end  of for loop
// check to see if required height is greater then actual height  of panel
                if(reheight>viewpanel.Height)
                    {
                            viewscrollbar.Visible=true;
                        viewscrollbar.Maximum=reheight+viewscrollbar.Height;
                        viewpanel.VerticalScroll.Enabled=false;
                        viewpanel.VerticalScroll.Visible=false;
// to output the Maximum value of scroll. 
                        label1.Text=Convert.ToString(viewscrollbar.Maximum);
                    }// end of if
            }
```

The maximum value of scroll is 1390. But the value of scroll don't go beyond 100. However, when the Verticalscroll bar, buildin scroll bar, is active then the value of verticalscrollbar, the custom scroll bar, goes beyond 100. Which make no sense to me at all.

Thank you for taking time to read through.